# Is reading register-sized data in `byteorder` efficient?

Tags: performance, rust, binary-data

The crate in the title is [`byteorder`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.4.3/byteorder/index.html).

Here is how we can read binary data from [`std::io::BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BufReader.html). `BufReader` implements the [`std::io::Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait. There is [an implementation](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.4.3/byteorder/trait.ReadBytesExt.html#implementors) of [`byteorder::ReadBytesExt`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.4.3/byteorder/trait.ReadBytesExt.html) for any type implementing `Read`. `ReadBytesExt` contains `read_u16` and other methods that read binary data. This implementation:

```
    fn read_u16<T: ByteOrder>(&mut self) -> Result<u16> {
        let mut buf = [0; 2];
        self.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
        Ok(T::read_u16(&buf))
    }
```

It passes a reference to `buf` to `BufReader`; I suppose it passes the address of `buf` in the stack. Hence the resulting `u16` is transferred from the internal buffer of `BufReader` (memory) to `buf` above (memory), probably, using `memcpy` or something. Wouldn't it be more efficient if `BufReader` implemented `ReadBytesExt` by reading data from its internal buffer directly? Or the compiler optimizes `buf` away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: It's all up to the Optimization Gods, but it should be efficient.**

The key optimization here is inlining, as usual, and the probabilities are on our side, but who knows...

As long as the call to `read_exact` is inlined, it should just work.

Firstly, it *can* be inlined. In Rust, "inner" calls are always statically dispatched -- there's no inheritance -- and therefore the type of the receiver (`self`) in `self.read_exact` is known at compile-time. As a result, the exact `read_exact` function being called is known at compile-time.

Of course, there's no telling *whether* it'll be inlined. The implementation is fairly short, so chances are good, but that's out of our hands.

Secondly, what happens if it's inlined? Magic!

You can see the implementation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/io/buffered/bufreader.rs.html#275):

```
fn read_exact(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<()> {
    if self.buffer().len() >= buf.len() {
        buf.copy_from_slice(&self.buffer()[..buf.len()]);
        self.consume(buf.len());
        return Ok(());
    }

    crate::io::default_read_exact(self, buf)
}
```

Once inlined, we therefore have:

```
fn read_u16<T: ByteOrder>(&mut self) -> Result<u16> {
    let mut buf = [0; 2];

    //  self.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
    if self.buffer().len() >= buf.len() {
        buf.copy_from_slice(&self.buffer()[..buf.len()]);
        self.consume(buf.len());
        Ok(())
    } else {
        crate::io::default_read_exact(self, buf)
    }?;

    Ok(T::read_u16(&buf))
}
```

Needless to say, all those `buf.len()` calls should be replaced by `2`.

```
fn read_u16<T: ByteOrder>(&mut self) -> Result<u16> {
    let mut buf = [0; 2];

    //  self.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
    if self.buffer().len() >= 2 {
        buf.copy_from_slice(&self.buffer()[..2]);
        self.consume(2);
        Ok(())
    } else {
        crate::io::default_read_exact(self, buf)
    }?;

    Ok(T::read_u16(&buf))
}
```

So we're left with `copy_from_slice`, a `memcpy` invoked with a *constant* size (2).

The trick is that `memcpy` is so special that it's a builtin in most compilers, and it certainly is in LLVM. And it's a builtin specifically so that in special cases -- such as a constant size being specified which happen to be a register size -- its codegen can be specialized to... a `mov` instruction in the case of x86/x64.

So, as long as `read_exact` is inlined, then `buf` should live in a register from beginning to end... in the happy case.

In the *cold path*, when `default_read_exact` is called, then the compiler will need to use the stack and pass a slice. That's fine. It should not happen often.

---

*If you find yourself repeatedly doing sequences of `u16` reads, however... you may find yourself better served by reading larger arrays, to avoid the repeated `if self.buffer().len() >= 2` checks.*